# Reload the page in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react application with different pages. On `Home` page i added the `<Prompt/>` component from `react-router-dom`.

```
const Home = () => {
  const data = true;
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Prompt when={!!data} message="Are you sure?" />
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The idea is next: user adds some data in the input and when he clicks on another page, the popup appears and if the user click on `ok` button, he should be redirected on another page. The functionality works good, but when user add some data in the input, click on the `Home` link menu, and after that clicks `Ok` on modal window, the data from the input still, but it should disappear from there. 
 Question: How to solve the last issue? I expect after user clicks on the `ok` the values from input should disappear. 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-cr2m4?file=/components/Home.js:71-266

Comment: The `input` is completely uncontrolled... guess you make it controlled, or remount it, or something similar. What have you tried? You may need to rethink your strategy as the [Prompt](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt) doesn't appear to have much functionality other than to allow, or prevent, navigation.

Comment: @DrewReese, i changed the component to controlled, but i doon't know how to detect when user click on the route, and after that to refresh that page. Could you help?

Comment: I don't see any benefit of clearing the input if the user decides to navigate from the page, it'll get unmounted anyway.

Comment: @DrewReese, even if it is unmounte, but the value still in the input, how to reset it after the user clicks?

Comment: I think you misunderstand... the user either cancels and stays on the page, or they hit ok and navigate away. If they navigate away, then the `Home` component, and `input` are unmounted. It's only odd if they are already on the home page and try to navigate to the home page, which is essentially a non-op as far as react-router-dom is concerned. Is the case where you want to clear the input?

Comment: @DrewReese, the case when i want to clear the input is next: after user clicks on  the home page and after that on `Ok` from modal window, he should still get a reseted page, like he accesed the page for the first time, without the values.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hackish, but you could send a generated GUID in route state to the home path, and check for this to have changed in response to allowing navigation to have occurred by clicking on the home page link. If the route state "id" is updated then reset the state.

index

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

...

<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/",
    state: uuidV4() // <-- generate an unique id
  }}
>
  Home
</Link>
```

Home

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Prompt, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const idRef = useRef(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (idRef.current !== state) {
      setValue("");
    }
  }, [idRef, state]);

  const data = true;
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Prompt when={!!data} message="Are you sure?" />
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit reload-the-page-in-react-js]